# How to show customized/formatted drop-down value in PrimeReact's AutoComplete?

Tags: reactjs, primereact

Please see my full [sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-demo-forked-dfyglk?file=/src/App.tsx) for this question.  I have a drop down using AutoCompete where the datasource is a list of countries.  I format the drop down values using itemTemplate to add the word "Country" in front.

```js
      const itemTemplate = (item: Country) => {
         return <div>Country {item.name}</div>;
      };


     return (
     <div className="card flex justify-content-center">
      <AutoComplete
        field="name"
        value={selectedCountry}
        suggestions={filteredCountries}
        completeMethod={search}
        onChange={(e: AutoCompleteChangeEvent) => setSelectedCountry(e.value)}
        itemTemplate={itemTemplate}
        selectedItemTemplate={itemTemplate}
        panelFooterTemplate={panelFooterTemplate}
        dropdown={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

When user clicks on this drop down the'd see

[image]

When they select a country I want to use only the country name "Afghanistan" to the call back but I want display "Country Afghanistan" in the box.

[image]

In order to do that, I use the selectedItemTemplate and I pass in the same function to prepend the word "Country".  However, when I do this, I only see the value [object Object].

[image]

How can I display exact what the user selected in the drop down?

Comment: For a `<select><option` they have both a display and a value - you want the value to be what you use; the display can be anything. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Note a similar example here with a name/value pair https://primereact.org/autocomplete/#objects of `{name: "United States", code:"USA"}` for example.

Comment: Yup, I got field="name" which ensure I display "United States" and send that same value back to any call back.  However, I want to display "Country United States", that same document told me to use itemTemplate and I got that working, the part that just does not work is if I select it, it displays "United States" and not "Country United States"

Comment: Not a react expert and certianly not on this plug-in but perhaps have a name/value/longname object then use that `<AutoComplete field="longname" value={selectedCountry}` instead of `<AutoComplete field="name" value={selectedCountry}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I'm unsure the PrimeReact document was not clear or it was me not getting it but it looks like I can set the selectedItemTemplate to call a function myUserConversionMethod directly.

selectedItemTemplate expects a string, so I can't used the existing function which returns JSX.Element, I just need to build one that produce a string value.

```js
      const myUserConversionMethod = (item: Country) => { 
        return "Country " + item.name;
      };

      return (
       <div className="card flex justify-content-center">
         <AutoComplete
          field="name"
          selectedItemTemplate={myUserConversionMethod}
          value={selectedCountry}
          suggestions={filteredCountries}
          completeMethod={search}
          onChange={(e: AutoCompleteChangeEvent) => 
          setSelectedCountry(e.value)}
          itemTemplate={itemTemplate}
          dropdown={true}/>
        </div>
      );
```